# Java class issue --Constructor not define error though it is defined

Tags: java

I have created two classes. One class for holding the data and other class for writing the data.

class which holds data is:

```
package favartist;

public class finallistofartist {

    private String artist1;
    private String artist2;

    public finallistofartist()
    {

    }

    public finallistofartist(String s1, String s2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        artist1=s1;
        artist2=s2;
    }

    public void printartistpairs()
    {
        System.out.println(artist1+" - "+artist2);
    }

    public void set(String s1, String s2) {
        artist1=s1;
        artist2=s2;
    }

}
```

Other class is in the same package:

Now I do below coding in the class which writes data:

```
int max=10;
finallistofartist[] artistgroup=new finallistofartist[max];
for(totalpairs=0;totalpairs<max;totalpairs++)                
artistgroup[totalpairs]=new finallistofartist("abcd","abcde");
```

But this keeps giving error that 
"The constructor finallistofartist(String, String) is undefined"

However it is defined properly.

Please help.

Comment: are you you are using the correct version of `finallistofartist`?  The code looks OK.

Comment: Save the file and compile again. Also, try to follow Java naming conventions. Use names like `someVar` for variables/methods and use names like `SomeClass` for classes.

Comment: Is this your only `finallistofartist` class, or is there another one lurking in some other directory somewhere?

Comment: You may be doing some other thing wrong. I just added your code in eclipse and I got no errors. Please check your import statements may be there is another class with same name finallistofartist imported in your file or something or else clean build again.

Comment: Please follow standard Java classname conventions. It should be `FinalListOfArtist` and `ArtistGroup`

Comment: Yeah, I keep seeing "all is to fart" in the middle of the class name.  Some capital letters would help.

Comment: Compile your "finallistofartist " file again. Its not compiled properly

Comment: And it may also be easier for humans to read if you named your methods like `printArtistPairs`.